# Will binaries compiled for Plan9 by Go work in 9front?

Tags: go, plan-9

I am working on a file manager for 9front/Plan9; dev work is done in Go v1.15 under 64-bit Ubuntu with cross-compilation to build Plan9 binaries.

Perhaps somebody known whether binaries compiled for `Plan9` by Go will work in `9front`?

Or, to put it differently, - how significantly has `9front` diverged from the `plan9` codebase?

Answer (score 1):

After reaching out to 9front@9front.org mailing list, I received confirmation that binaries compiled by Go for Plan9 work in both `9front` and `Plan9`